# PHP include directories

Tags: php, url, include, directory

I'm trying to figure out how to get my php includes to work properly from files in different directories.

For example, I have a `header.php` for my layout which is included in the `index.php` - it's located in the `root/` directory. Then, I have a page located at `root/pages/etc/lib.php` - It also needs to use the `header.php`. Now, obviously I could do a `include "header.php"` for the index and a `include "../../header.php"` for the `lib.php` file, but then I run into another issue...

My `header.php` also has a php include of it's own, and the relative path is relative to the original page (`index.php` or `lib.php`) and NOT the `header.php`.

Is the solution to simply give the full URL for the includes or is there another way to do this? Can I do URL for any included php files and it will work?

Comment: You should have a constant variable that is NOT relative. Then have all your includes prefixed with this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers don't allow http wrappers in includes. You can do it with the document root:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

You can put it in a var and use it with every include. (Or define it)

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it:
`include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$pathToYourIncludeFileOnTheServer;`

Another is to set the php include_path in the php.ini. If you include a file php looks in the directories specified in include_path if a file is matching the include and if so chooses that file.

Including directly via http://www.server.com/include.php is often a problem since allow_url_include is sometimes disabled in the php.ini if you are using a free webhosting or something comparable.